# perform action after assert statement

Tags: groovy, soapui, assertion

Problem statement : Fail the test step and write something in the file, in Script Assertion step.

Description : I am using script assertion in SoapUI. I am validating the API response, if its successful, hit DB and get the value, if the response from API and DB value does not match, write to file and fail the test step - if they match, do nothing.

The code that I have currently, writes to the file, but it does not fail the test step.

```
def response = "test:testrunnwer"
if (status == "200 OK")
        {
            def splitResponse = (response.split(':',2))
            def finalResult = splitResponse[1].substring(2,splitResponse[1].length()-3)
                def sql = Sql.newInstance(context.expand( '${#Project#dbName}' ), context.expand( '${#Project#dbUser}' ), context.expand( '${#Project#dbPassword}' ), context.expand( '${#Project#sqlDriver}' ))
                sql.eachRow('select <<column_name>> as result from <<table_name>>') {
                    rw -> if (!(rw.result == finalResult)){
                            wfFail.append(rawRequest+"  "+status+"  "+splitResponse[1]+"\r\n")
                        }
                    }
                sql.close()
            }
```

`testRunner.fail()` does not work here. I read somewhere that `testRunner` is not accessible in Script Assertion.

Other approach that I tried was :

```
sql.eachRow(context.expand( '${emarketingDataTagsList#SQLquery}' )) {
                    rw -> assert(rw.result == finalResult) : wfFail.append(rawRequest+" "+status+"  "+splitResponse[1]+"\r\n")
                    }
```

This also does not yield the result (step fails, but nothing is written in the file), I get this info 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkQSy.png)

Comment: `wfFail` - where is defined? what does it have?

Comment: Kumar, check the answer and see if that is useful.

Comment: Have you got chance to try the solution?

Comment: Thank you @rao. I was able to make this work using  _threw new Error()_ .
But, when i used, _context.testRunner.fail()_ , it gave an error, "cannot invoke method fail() on null object".
Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: To answer your first question, _wfFail_ is defined above _response_.

Answer (score 0):

> perform action after assert statement

The action would work provided assertion passes. Otherwise, it won't as the execution is stopped on assertion failure.

There is an alternative way to accomplish this. Here use `if..else` instead of `assert`

Say:

```
//Doing negative comparison Since nothing to do when equal
if (rw.result != finalResult) { 
 wfFail.append(rawRequest+" "+status+"  "+splitResponse[1]+"\r\n")
}
//Do other stuff or repeach eachRow of sql
//After completion
if(wfFail.toString()) {
  threw new Error(wfFail.toString()
}
```

> testRunner.fail() does not work here. I read somewhere that testRunner is not accessible in Script Assertion.

That is correct. `testRunner` object is initialized in *Groovy Script* Test step, but not in *Script Assertion*. 
However, you can use below for the same:

**Change from**: `testRunner.fail()`
**To**: `context.testRunner.fail()`

Hope this is helpful.